# Binding from ItemsControl DataTemplate to parent UserControls DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I want to create an user control which contains ItemsControl with buttons and I want to bind theirs contents to user controls dependency property (something like DisplayMemberPath property).

My xaml.cs code:

```
public partial class ButtonsItemsSourceControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(ButtonsItemsSourceControl), null);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMember", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonsItemsSourceControl), null);

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (ICollection<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public string DisplayMember
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberProperty, value); }
    }

    public ButtonsItemsSourceControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

My xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.ButtonsItemsSourceControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480" x:Name="root">

<ItemsControl x:Name="ctrl" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=root}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content= ?????/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

What binding expression should I write in Content property to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity, are you asking how to bind a child property to a parent property?

[RelativeSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406166/binding-to-an-ancestor-in-wpf)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @justin. I forgot to mention that I am doing it in application for Windows Phone and there is no FindAncestor mode in RelativeSource. There are only TemplatedParent and Self modes ...