# Zoom in/out in Canvas - where Canvas is in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, mvvm

I would like to add Zoom in/out functionality into my program. My problem is, what the Canvas is defined in the App.xaml file:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:ClassData}">
            <Canvas>
                <View:ClassDataUserControl/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:Connector}">
            <Canvas>
                <View:ConnectorUserControl/>
            </Canvas>
 </DataTemplate>
```

And I would like to add a slider in a UserControl, that controls the zoom.

My code for the UserControl looks like this:

```
<Slider x:Name="zoomSlider" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="10" Value="1"/>
```

I have read several proposals on the Internet, but I haven't found any where the Canvas is in the App.xaml file.

Comment: Bind to [ancestor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3406166/1997232)? It's hard to imagine what you want, because slider will zoom itself as well (should looks ugly).

Comment: @Sinatr The Slider is in another UserControl called SidePanelUserControl, so the slider will not zoom itself out.

Comment: Then your question is basically how to communicate between VMs. You can create property in main window VM, which will be changed by `SidePanelUserControl` VM and monitored by another `UserControl` (`INotifyPropertyChanged`?) to change zoom.