# Bind a custom property to a template in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a template for a button, that will show an image (icon) instead of text. 
I want to be able to assign different images to different instances of that button, for example:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource iconButton}" ImageSource="Sources/icon.png">
```

or alternatively:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource iconButton}">
    <Image Source="...">
</Button>
```

(but I still want to be able to style the image in the template, so I wouldn't need to worry about color and size when I use it - so simply rendering the image as content won't do).

*Example code*:

Here I am using the image as a mask to render it in whatever color I want:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="iconButton">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- add the "content to image source" converter-->
            <converters:ContentToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ContentToImageSourceConverter"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource foreground_color}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle"  Width="45" Height="45" Fill="{DynamicResource foreground_color}" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="45" Height="45" Fill="{DynamicResource foreground_color}">
                            <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                                <!--How to accomplish this?-->
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{TemplateBinding Property=Content "/>
                            </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="circle" Property="Opacity" Value="0.15"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="circle" Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Have a look at the line where it says *"how to accomplish this"*. I am using an image as a source but I want the image to be defined whenever you use the button, for example:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource iconButton}" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <Image Source="/Sources/settings_icon.png"/>
                </Button>
```

I **do not** want to simply render the image as a content of the button because I'm using it as a mask for something else, thus I can change the foreground color and have the icons render in a different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a custom control, with one dependency property of the image source. Have you tried this?

And then you will use it like this

```
<MyCustomButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" ImageSource = Sources/settings_icon.png">
            </MyCustomButton>
```

The simplest way to do it:

1. Add UserControl to your project
2. In xaml just add one button
3. Add style to this control and set it to the button
4. Add dependency property, and link it to the image source (in style) by binding. Here you need also to have specified a source of binding.
   {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}

Second way:

1. Make an class which is deriving form the Button class.
2. Add one dependency property, with the image source object.
3. In Style Specify a binding for the source property of the image control, it has to have the same name as he dependency property. I think that you will also need to specify the source of the binding as a Ancestor, because it could not be able to find the binding source.
   Check here to see the syntax.
   [Binding to an ancestor in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406166/binding-to-an-ancestor-in-wpf)

In both ways the usage will look same.

Comment: Hey I'm new to WPF so I haven't really learned how to use "custom control" yet, but I'll check that out. thanks!